# MariaDB - Switching Antelope to Barracuda - there are any risks with existent databases?

Tags: mariadb, innodb, barracuda

While trying to install latest moodle version, I've got blocking message regarding the need to use Barracuda Format for InnoDB.
I've already the ITOP (https://www.combodo.com/itop-193) application installed, then I would like to know if there is any risk on changing from Antelope to Barracuda.
I've read the mariadb documentation (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-file-format/), but I was not able to understand if I can face potential issues with the databases that where created with Antelope format.

Comment: The switch from Antelope to Barracuda was years ago; I have not heard of any issues.  If the app _requires_ each table to be Barracuda, then there might need to be some action taken.  What version of MariaDB (before and after) is involved?

Comment: Are you using Replication?  There could be some issues in the order of upgrading the servers.

Comment: Hi, I'm not using replication.  I've discovered that the mariadb version has already Barracuda as default, but the the moodle installer is not able to recognize this. I've solved adding the config option (also the deprecated options) as suggested in moodle site.